# Advanced Custom Fields Not Displaying on Desired Page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Advanced Custom Field (ACF) Plugin for my Wordpress blogs. Each blog has the same general heading/logo to the page.

> [Immigration Law](http://www.knowingimmigrationlaw.com)
>
> [Health Law](http://www.knowinghealthlaw.com)

The two elements that generally change are the standard colors associated with the blog's name and the name of the blog (i.e. Health vs Immigration).

I've added a few ACF fields into a new group (blog_type, blog_name, blog_color) and inserted them into the header.php file where I want them. I've also assigned them to the following location rules:

> User, is equal to, Administrator (and)
>
> Page, is equal to, Home

When I choose Update and proceed to the home page, the new fields should be there but are not.

I did a little digging and found that I needed to add the exported info that it generates to my functions.php page in my child theme. But when I do that and go back to my Group details in the plugin menu, all but one of the fields are gone.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

> Wordpress version: 4.2.2
>
> Parent Theme: Elegant Themes - Divi (version 2.3.1)
>
> ACF Plugin Version: 4.4.2

EDIT:
Here's the code I added to my header.php

```
<h1>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">knowing<span style="color: <?php the_field('blog_color');?>;"><?php the_field('blog_name');?></span><?php the_field('blog_type');?></a>
</h1>
```

This is the code that the export function gave me for my functions.php file:

```
if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
{
    register_field_group(array (
        'id' => 'acf_blog-details',
        'title' => 'Blog Details',
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_55a40afe0bf59',
                'label' => 'Blog Color',
                'name' => 'blog_color',
                'type' => 'color_picker',
                'required' => 1,
                'default_value' => 'rgb(210,120,40)',
            ),
            array (
                'key' => 'field_55a41857b2d0f',
                'label' => 'Blog Name',
                'name' => 'blog_name',
                'type' => 'text',
                'required' => 1,
                'default_value' => 'Blog',
                'placeholder' => 'Blog Name',
                'prepend' => '',
                'append' => '',
                'formatting' => 'html',
                'maxlength' => '',
            ),
            array (
                'key' => 'field_55a41859b2d10',
                'label' => 'Blog Type',
                'name' => 'blog_type',
                'type' => 'radio',
                'instructions' => 'Choose a type of Blog',
                'required' => 1,
                'choices' => array (
                    'blog' => 'blog',
                    'relations' => 'relations',
                ),
                'other_choice' => 0,
                'save_other_choice' => 0,
                'default_value' => '',
                'layout' => 'vertical',
            ),
        ),
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'ef_user',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'administrator',
                    'order_no' => 0,
                    'group_no' => 0,
                ),
                array (
                    'param' => 'page',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => '23',
                    'order_no' => 1,
                    'group_no' => 0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array (
            'position' => 'normal',
            'layout' => 'no_box',
            'hide_on_screen' => array (
                0 => 'custom_fields',
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order' => 0,
    ));
}
```

EDIT 2:

Okay I found something strange out, when I removed the **User = Admin** out from the Location Rules, it showed up. But I only want Admins to see that. Not sure what to do.

Comment: And how are you calling the fields in your page? I would recommend start doing a sample without your condition rules. Just to check if the basic is working.

Comment: We need to see your actual code.

Comment: added them to the original post.

Comment: I should add that it displays everything fine when I manually enter the fields and values into standard custom fields. The problem is on the back end of Home. None of the custom fields are displaying on there.

Comment: Edit 2 has some updates.

Comment: You don't need the exported fields in your functions file unless you are importing to another site. For a global function (i.e. more than just home page) it should be done on an options page. Can you take a screenshot of your current fields as they appear in ACF as well as the conditional rules of where they appear?

Comment: I wonder if this is a race condition. Not sure where you are running the code, but try running the function as the callback to the acf/init hook, or something like the 'plugins_loaded' hook. add_action('acf/init', function() {/* your code here */}); Reason I suggest is that the if condition may not see the 'register_field_group' yet if the plugin hasn't fully loaded when your code loads.